# Figuring out QuadCurveTo's parameters

Tags: java, math, javafx

Could you guys help me figuring out `QuadCurveTo`'s 4 parameters , I tried to find some information on [`QuadCurveTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/QuadCurveTo.html), but it's hard to understand without a picture. I know those 4 parameters draw `2 lines` to control the path , but how we know/calculate exactly which coordinates the object will pass throught by only knowing those 2 path-controller. Are there some `formulas`?

```
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition.OrientationType;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.QuadCurveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class _6 extends Application {

    public Rectangle r;

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {

        r = new Rectangle(50, 80, 80, 90); 
        r.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.ORANGE);
        r.setStrokeWidth(5);
        r.setStroke(Color.ANTIQUEWHITE);

        Path path = new Path();  
         path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(100.0f, 400.0f));
         path.getElements().add(new QuadCurveTo(150.0f, 60.0f, 100.0f, 20.0f));
         PathTransition pt = new PathTransition(Duration.millis(1000), path);

        pt.setDuration(Duration.millis(10000));
        pt.setNode(r);
        pt.setPath(path);
        pt.setOrientation(OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
        pt.setCycleCount(4000);
        pt.setAutoReverse(true);

        pt.play();

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(r), 500, 700));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

You can find those coordinates on this `new QuadCurveTo(150.0f, 60.0f, 100.0f, 20.0f)` line, and below is the sample picture of `Quadratic Bezier`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezier_curve)

```
B(t)=(1-t)*(1-t)*P0 + 2*(1-t)*t*P1 + t*t*P2, 0<=t<=1
```

Here P0 is the start point, P1 the control point, and P2 the end point. Note that `t` might not be equal to the time point of your transition, as the transition has a modifiable interpolator; however the path will pass through all points defined by this curve. In your example, `P0=(100, 400)`, `P1=(150, 60)`, and `P2=(100, 20)`.

The interpretation is that you take a linear interpolation between the start point and the control point (call that `Q0(t)`) and a linear interpolation between the control point and the end point (`Q1(t)`); then the curve is the linear interpolation between `Q0(t)` and `Q1(t)` at `t`: `B(t)=(1-t)*Q0(t)+t*Q1(t)`

Comment: James , does **t** simply means a kind of distance ? and always increment from 0 ?

Comment: `t` is the parameter for the points on the curve. `t=0` is the start point, `t=1` is the end point. I just meant that you shouldn't assume `t` varied linearly with time as the transition progresses. You can force it to by calling `pt.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR)`